# Where can I find a replacement green colored porcelain toilet?

Tags: toilet, replacement

Do any of the manufacturers still make green colored porcelain toilets?  The existing one is an American Standard model probably from the 60's and it is green porcelain.  Most of the bathroom is green tile so I don't think a white replacement would look right, but it seems that none of the manufacturers I have looked at make green colored toilets anymore.  Any ideas?

Comment: Ideally, I would like a new low-flow toilet just in green or olive, not an older version.

Comment: I saw a variety of colors at my local Lowes just a couple weeks ago (pink, brown, black, white, cream, etc). However, green does not seem to be one of them :(

Comment: Closing as a [shopping question](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/607/can-we-discourage-shop-for-me-type-questions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this place on the net that has a lot of vintage plumbing. They had some green sinks and soap dishes and a pink toilet.

I didn't see a green toilet, but it looks like they do a lot of salvage work and their inventory changes frequently. Might be worthwhile to drop them an e-mail and have them notify you if one comes in.

[Historic House Parts](http://www.historichouseparts.com/vintage_toilets.htm)

Also, you could try online classified sites like e-bay. Here is an add for a [turquoise/green toilet](http://fortwayne.olx.com/retro-turquoise-green-toilet-and-sink-iid-10483821).

As to the thought of installing a monstrosity like that, may God have mercy on your soul. =)

Answer (score 3):

We have several "ReStore"s in my area that have old building materials that people have donated. I always see old turquoise, coral, powder blue, ... sinks, toilets, etc. there. I imagine you can find something similar in your area to browse.

Answer (score 1):

[A1 New & Used Plumbing & Heating](http://www.antiqueplumbingandradiators.com/) in Somerville, MA, are most known for their radiators, but also have sinks, toilet covers, etc.  If they don't have a green toilet, I bet they would at least know where to look.

Answer (score 1):

Kohler makes Tea Green one available by special order thru home depot.